# How do you connect IBM Lombardi BPM to Azure Service Bus topics?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, ibm-bpm, azure-servicebus-topics

We are considering using Azure Service Bus (or Service Bus for Windows Server) to publish business events as pub/sub topics generated by our .Net services. We want these events to be picked up by IBM Lombardi BPM (without polling). It isn't clear that Lombardi BPM V8.5.6 can subscribe to Azure (or Service Bus for Windows Server) topics.

1. Can this be done with out-of-the-box Lombardi BPM?
2. How do you do it?

Comment: The name containing 'Lombardi' hints, that your version of BPM is rather old. Could you add the version of the software you are using?

Comment: Updated in the original post also. IBM Lombardi V8.5.6.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn574799.aspx), Service Bus for Windows Server should be compatible with JMS (I am myself a Java guy, so I am not familiar with the Service Bus).

Given that my assumption is correct, here you can find some examples of integrating JMS in IBM BPM: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/bpm/library/techarticles/1510_liu-trs/1510_liu.html

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSFPJS_8.5.6/com.ibm.wbpm.wle.editor.doc/topics/sending_message_events.html